# Isolating ProgrammingError in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to debug a problem inserting data into an a Microsoft SQL database. The error message I keep getting is:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
> Driver][SQL Server]The incoming Tabular Data Stream (TDS) for the
> Remote Procedure Call (RPC) protocol is not correct. Parameter 16
> (''): The specified value is not a valid instance of the float data
> type. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an
> invalid value is data of a numeric type whose decimal places exceed
> the precision value. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)")

I (believe) I understand the problem but I can't isolate which values are tripping it. I made sure all the columns in the dataframe are exactly the same name and order of the database, but obviously something still isn't jiving. My question is: Where exactly is this error message pointing too when it says 'Parameter 16'. Is is a row? Is it a column? Is it zero-indexing?

I unfortunately can't easily provide data or examples but I can at least provide my sql insert code for more context:

```
with engine.begin() as conn:
    stmt = insert(reflection)
    values_list = df.to_dict(orient='records')
    conn.execute(stmt, values_list)
```

Any tips?

Comment: Can you provide the SQL and Pandas DataFrame data types? Also, do any of the DataFrame columns contain missing values? You can check with `df.isna().any()`

Comment: "I unfortunately can't easily provide data or examples" - Then we can't easily help you. Try to create a [mcve] that illustrates your issue and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: @GordThompson, i understand what you're saying, but if I could reproduce the problem I'd be able to solve it. The question was more to help understand the error message

Comment: @JasonCook, I have inspected the data, both with methods and manually (its about 31x34). It seems to be all as it should but I can't whittle down to the value that's tripping the error here. As mentioned, something just isn't jiving between the dataset and the databank and I'm running out of ideas how to isolate it.

Comment: If you're using pyodbc then it is generating an `sp_prepexec` call which has three (3) parameter values before the (DataFrame) row values begin. Therefore I would expect parameter 16 to be the value for the 13th column.

Comment: Are you using `fast_executemany=True` in your `create_engine()` call?

Comment: That is useful to know that it's the 13th column, there are values missing here but this column is an object column and the dataframe a string, I don't understand why a float error is being tripped. I'll play with that further

I am suing pyodbc but I am not using fast_executemany as I wan't aware of the parameter. What does speed have to do with this here?

Comment: Thank you both for your help. There was some discontinuity in my dataflow and one column that was supposed to be a string kept being changed into a float before the import. @GordThompson it's definitely helpful to know where these error messages are pointing to for the future.